# Use SQL Variables to Decline/Diminish Applying Balance

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

So I have three tables in a MSSQL 2012 Database;

DOCUMENTS (varchar EMPID, varchar CODE, varcahr DOCID, AMT decimal(5,2))

PAYMENTS (varchar EMPID, varchar CODE, varcahr AMT)

APPLICATIONS (varchar DOCID, varchar EMPID, decimal(5,2) AMT)

I already have 2 tables working great, Documents and Payments

```
 Documents looks like this:
 BEN12, FLY, 1234-10, 5.00
 BEN12, FLY, 1234-11, 10.00
 BEN12, CAR, 2234-20, 4.00
 MKE10, FLY, 1234-13, 6.00

 PAYMENTS looks like this:
 BEN12, FLY, 8.00
 BEN12, CAR, 2.00
 MKE10, FLY, 3.00

 and Applicaitons needs to look like this:
 BEN12, 1234-10,5.00
 BEN12, 1234-11,3.00
 BEN12, 2234-20,2.00
 MKE10, 1234-13,3.00
```

I am pre-loading document ID's, CODEs and '0.00' amounts into APPLICATIONS (using an insert from DOCUMENTS) to help with my code.  But I am having the darnedest time with the calculation.

I thought maybe using a global variable would help but its giving me a result set that is just full of the same record listed over and over.  Here is where I am at:

```
`declare @currentCust varchar(20) =''
 declare @LastCust varchar(20) =''
 declare @AmtBal decimal (5,2) ='50'
 declare @applyBal decimal (5,2) ='0'
 declare @CurrentDoc varchar(20) =''
 declare @LastDoc varchar(20) =''
 declare @CurrentCod varchar(20) =''
 declare @LastCod varchar(20) =''

 begin
 UPDATE APPLICATIONS
 set CODE = DOCS.DED,
 @CurrentDoc = DOCS.doc_NO,
 @currentCust = DOCS.CUST_NO,
 @CurrentCod = DOCS.DED,
 CUST_ID = DOCS.CUST_NO,
 @AmtBal = case when @currentCust = @LastCust and @CurentCod = @LastCod 
    THEN @AmtBal ELSE RCV.AMT END,
 @applyBal = case 
        WHEN DOCS.balance <= @AmtBal 
        THEN DOCS.balance
        when DOCS.balance > @AmtBal
        THEN @AmtBal
 @LastCust = DOCS.CUST_NO,
 @LastCod = @CurrentCod,
 AMT = @ApplyBal,
 @AmtBal = @AmtBal- @applyBal

 from DOCUMENTS DOCS left join RECEIVE RCV 
 on DOCS.CUST_NO = RCV.CUST_ID and DOCS.DED = RCV.CODE

 ----IT WORKS IF I ADD THIS
  WHERE DOC_ID = DOCS.DOC_NO
  ---- YAY!
 end
```

`

I guess I don't know enough about whats happening to those variables while the SQL record iteration occurs, but its certainly not giving me the output I was expecting.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks all!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2012

Comment: It looks like you really want an `insert` rather than an update. You also appear do be doing something in a kind of loop which probably calls for a cursor. While it may be possible to use avoid the cursor you'll likely need to specify more requirements before anybody will dive in to help; it's too much effort to decipher with so little to go on. Check out one of the SSMS cursor templates to see if that gets you started.

Comment: Item 1) The math doesn't add up. Seems like the Ben12 1234-12 Applications record should be $2 instead of $3. Item 2) Poor design for applications table. Better design puts an identify column on Documents and Payments, and then Applications just has fields for DocumentID, PaymentID, and remaining balance.

Answer (score 0):

well that was silly!!!

I forgot to link the UPDATE table to the From Set using

```
  WHERE DOC_ID = DOCS.DOC_NO
```

right before the END at the very bottom.

Now it works like a champ!!!